# Changing the presentation of a matrix plot

Tags: plotting

In a MatrixPlot (1,1) is in the NW corner. Is it possible to have it in the SW one ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`DataReversed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataReversed.html) option of [`MatrixPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPlot.html),

```
mat = ConstantArray[0, {4, 4}];
mat[[;; 2, ;; 2]] = {{1, 2}, {3, 0}};
MatrixPlot[mat, DataReversed -> #] & /@ {{False, False}, 
   {False, True}, {True, False}, {True, True}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think it will be more clear if you have `mat[[{1, 2}, {1, 2}]] = {{1, 2}, {3, 0}};`